# What is loose coupling?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was studying few concepts of **MVC** on **MSDN**, and i reached on a point where they have written a word **"loose coupling between the three main components of an MVC"**.

I searched a lot about the loose coupling on google. But i got different kind of answers every time.

Even i got a new word **tight coupling** and **tight cohesion**.

Can anyone define the word properly, and what it means exactly.

I'm looking forward for your replies.

Thanks.

Comment: and also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226977/what-is-loose-coupling-please-provide-examples

Comment: @Habib I've gotten exact answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loose coupling is simply writing software in such a way that all your classes can work independently without relying on each other. Since you're studying MVC I'll use it as an example to demonstrate the concept of loose coupling:

**1) Tight coupling**

ASP.NET Web forms are tightly coupled. Each .aspx page is dependent on it's code behind page which makes automated testing a nightmare

**2) Loose coupling**

ASP.NET MVC is loosely coupled.The logic is separated into 3 parts:

1. Model - Contains your classes and business logic
2. View - Displays the application UI based on the model data
3. Controller -  Respond to an oncoming URL request and select the appropriate view

The three parts can be changed independently without affecting one another and thanks to the principle of [separation of concern](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/07/30/clean-separation-of-concerns-in-mvc.aspx) we can easily write automated tests to test our Models without having to rely on Views.

Comment: Thanks, loose coupling explanation was really helpful.