# Separation of concern vs encapsulation vs loose coupling vs spaghetti code

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

What's the exact meaning and relation between these terms. It looks like many people confuse them a lot.

My idea is that separation of concern is what you get with encapsulation.

Loose coupling is in some blog confused with separation of concerns, wheras in other is just a separation as components that do not know each other.

Spaghetti code is tangled code. So not following the 3 above concepts can lead to spaghetti code.

Is it correct?

Comment: About loose coupling, look at the IOC pattern, which can be resumed by the great Hollywood principle: `Do not call us we will call you`.
And about `So not following the 3 above concepts can lead to spaghetti code`, the answer is YES.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation and loose coupling are largely abstract ideas, which is to say that their might not be ***exact*** meanings as you put it. So with subtle cases, it can often come down to opinion. However, here is the jist of it...

### Encapsulation.

Encapsulation just means protecting (encapsulating) class members that should not be accessible (or do not need to be accessible) from the outside of the class. It allows you to define exactly how that variable/method should be interacted with. For example;

```
class A{
    private int a;
    public void setA(int a){
        this.a = a; 
    }
} 
class B{
    public int b;
}
```

In class `A`, the `a` variable is encapsulated. You can only set `a` from outside this object instance through the defined method which allows us to define exactly how it can be allowed to be set. It also means you can not retrieve the value of `a` because we have not defined a method to allow it.

In class `B` in contrast, `b` is public and anyone from outside the class can do whatever they want with it. Which, is not very well encapsulated. Think of Encapsulation as having members surrounded by a protective capsule, which makes sure that members are only interacted with in a good-predefined way.

Links:

- [Programming Encapsulation Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)
- [What is Encapsulation?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/what-is-encapsulation-in-java-and-oops.html)

### Loose Coupling

Coupling refers to the degree that two classes are bound to each other, or have knowledge of the workings of each other. If two concrete classes could not work without the existence of the other class they are considered tightly coupled. Loose coupling is probably more of an abstract concept than Encapsulation, but they do relate to each other. If, for example, a class' variables are not encapsulated, then any class that uses it is said to be tightly coupled with it if it uses those variables.

```
class A{
    public int a;
} 
class B{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        A ay = new A();
        ay.a = 7;
    }
}
```

In the above example classes `A` and `B` are tightly coupled, because `B` has in depth knowledge of the variable states of `A` and could not run if class `A` did not exist.

The wiki says the following on Loose coupling;

> Strong coupling occurs when a dependent class contains a pointer
>   directly to a concrete class which provides the required behavior. The
>   dependency cannot be substituted, or its "signature" changed, without
>   requiring a change to the dependent class. Loose coupling occurs when
>   the dependent class contains a pointer only to an interface, which can
>   then be implemented by one or many concrete classes.

Links:

- [Loose Coupling wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)
- [Loose Coupling examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226977/what-is-loose-coupling-please-provide-examples)