# Syntax trouble with inline access specifiers

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am very new to object oriented programming in c++ and I am having some difficulty with syntax when access specifiers are used inline with variables, classes, or functions. The code below is not mine. It is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226977/what-is-loose-coupling-please-provide-examples) post. Judging by the popularity of the thread I'm sure others got it to compile. However I am having difficulty.

```
public class CartEntry
{
    public float Price;
    public int Quantity;
}

public class CartContents
{
    public CartEntry[] items;
}

public class Order
{
    private CartContents cart;
    private float salesTax;

    public Order(CartContents cart, float salesTax)
    {
        this.cart = cart;
        this.salesTax = salesTax;
    }

    public float OrderTotal()
    {
        float cartTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.items.Length; i++)
        {
            cartTotal += cart.items[i].Price * cart.items[i].Quantity;
        }
        cartTotal += cartTotal*salesTax;
        return cartTotal;
    }
}
```

I tried a simple class to identify the problem

This compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
class C{
    int i;
    };
int main(){}
```

This does not:

```
#include <iostream>
class C{
    public int i;
    };
int main(){}
```

nor does this:

```
#include <iostream>
public class C{
    int i;
    };
int main(){}
```

This does:

```
#include <iostream>
class C{
    public: int i;
    };
int main(){}
```

This does not:

```
#include <iostream>
public: class C{
    int i;
    };
int main(){}
```

I am using the GNU c++ compiler V6.3.1 without any build flags.  If this syntax is incorrect, why do I see it demonstrated so often.  If it is correct, am I missing a compiler option, header file, or something else?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add the link to the post you were referring to.

Comment: Code appears in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747980/java-array-assignment-confusion-in-shopping-cart; yup, Java.

Comment: The first code sample is not C++.

Comment: Original source of the code may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226977/what-is-loose-coupling-please-provide-examples/227334#227334.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simply that your example post discusses Java instead of C++. The syntax for access specifiers and *this* pointers (as well as many other items) is different.

Comment: Interesting.  I never tried Java.  I never realized how similar the languages looked.  Thanks!

Comment: @mreff555 Yes, a lot of the syntax in Java is C-like. I suggest that you do all of the research you can before making a post in the future though. :)

Comment: For the record, the post I was referring to was this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226977/what-is-loose-coupling-please-provide-examples. Not the one referenced by melpomene. Java is not explicitly mentioned in the post or tags and I found the post with the search string "c++ loose coupling".  I would agree that it is important to do research before posting. but as a new programmer with no experience in Java I really had no way of knowing.