# Java exclusive methods to other classes

Tags: java, class, methods

Is there a way in Java to have methods that can be accessed by certain Classes?

```
class CommonClass{
  void methodAvailableForClassA() {code goes here}
  void methodAvailableForClassB() {code goes here}
}
class A{
  CommonClass cc;
  public void useCC(){
    cc.methodAvalableForClassA();
  }
}
class B{
  CommonClass cc;
  public void useCC(){
    cc.methodAvalableForClassB();
  }
}
```

What I am asking is if there is a way to make available methods to certain classes

Comment: Sort of, by arranging your classes in packages carefully. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more information on Java access control.

Comment: Not directly but there are many ways to achieve similar results access control, inner classes, interfaces, etc. Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is having some CommonClass methods available exclusive to Class A and some methods exclusive to Class B

Comment: Sounds like a bad design, you should probably have `CommonClass` as an interface or abstract class, and have separate implementations for classes `A` and `B`

Comment: It's not really clear why you'd want to do this. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments you're not providing enough context and I suspect that this problem can be avoided with a better design.

That said, you can "hack" it by [`overloading`](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java) the same method with the different types of the classes, and have the objects send themselves to the method:

```
class CommonClass{
    void methodAvailableForClass(A a) {...}
    void methodAvailableForClass(B b) {...}
}
class A{
    CommonClass cc;
    public void useCC(){
        cc.methodAvailableForClass(this);
    }
}
class B{
    CommonClass cc;
    public void useCC(){
        cc.methodAvailableForClass(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

You are asking the wrong question, you are asking about a solution that is inappropriate and not the problem.

You should keep methods that are localized to a specific class specialization or implementation of an interface with that implementation.

This is know as [`High Cohesion` and `Loose Coupling`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000762/what-does-low-in-coupling-and-high-in-cohesion-mean).

You are trying to do the exact opposite of both of these things, and that is not a good path to be going down.

Any time you have something that is a catch all like `CommonClass` you are creating a tangled mess of dependencies on completely unrelated things.

#### Solution:

Those methods that are specialized for each of those classes should be **owned by those classes that use them**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere you should be looking for loose coupling - as long as `ClassA` and `ClassB` both know about `CommonClass` you've got strongly coupled code and you've got this kind of problem. However, if you split out separate interfaces which represent the various roles which `CommonClass` may play then you may be able to pass an instance of CommonClass to each of `ClassA` and `ClassB` but as an instance of separate roles which only give the client classes access to specific methods.

e.g.

```
 public interface RoleForA {
     void methodAvailableForClassA();
 }

 public interface RoleForB {
     void methodAvailableForClassB();
 }

 public class CommonClass implements RoleForA, RoleForB {
    ....
 }

 public class ClassA {
    private final RoleForA cc;
    public void useCC(){
        cc.methodAvailableForClassA();
    }
 }

 public class ClassB{
    private final RoleForB cc;
    public void useCC(){
        cc.methodAvailableForClassB();
    }
 }
```

The major caveat here is that `CommonClass`  shouldn't just be a dumping ground for all kinds of unrelated functionality. It needs to maintain cohesiveness so you should only do this for the right reason. One example of that might be providing a read-only interface to `CommonClass` to `ClassA` and a write-only interface to `ClassB`. The other thing to be aware of is that the interfaces involved shouldn't be simply tailored to the ClassA/B use cases or else any loose-coupling is purely illusory.