# Using Aurelia Store what is the best way to copy your state within Actions?

Tags: aurelia, reducers, aurelia-store, immer.js

What are some ways in which to deep clone my state inside an Action?

Possible solutions I’ve seen are [Immer.js](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer), `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)`, or create a recursive function which does a deep clone. I was even thinking of recreating what Redux does and create [Reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) and combine them for my entire state but there are reasons which I decided against it. I like in Aurelia store how I can [push Actions](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/store#what-are-actions) to the store, inside each Custom Element’s bind() method. I believe this is a better way because it promotes [high cohesion and low coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000762/what-does-low-in-coupling-and-high-in-cohesion-mean). Whereas with Redux I had all my Actions and Reducers centralized with the store.

I’ve never used Immer.js and I was wondering what are some Pros and Cons of using it?

I like the idea of using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)` because it ensures my state is serializable at all times. Which will be good if I want to persist my state to some type of storage. It allows me to identify problems early like when I tried to use Set and Map object types and I quickly found out that those don’t serilize/deserialize with the above methods. But I’m wondering if my store grows too large will `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)` become too slow?

Then there is the option of just creating a recursive function which copies my state. Has anyone tried this?

Thanks

**EDIT - September 26, 2018**
I also asked this question on the aurelia discourse forum and received some helpful responses there. 
https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/using-aurelia-store-what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-your-state-within-actions/

Comment: It seems you have already got an answer on discourse forum. Can you help post a link so it can also benefit other folks?

Comment: Added the discourse link as an edit to the post