Architecture design for divide the subsystems
When you do architecture design, you usually divide the subsystems. Is there any methodology to divide the subsystems?
Are architectural patterns like hexagonal architecture, clean architecture, etc. a single application? Or can they be used when dividing subsystems?
Is there any methodology for dividing the system into subsystems?

Similar to the DDD methodology？


Are architectural patterns like hexagonal architecture, clean architecture, etc. a single application?

Yes, they basically are.

Is there any methodology for dividing the system into subsystems?

If by "subsystem" you mean splitting an application in multiple deployable units, then there are several:

Microservices architecture (one of the most popular nowdays). The two main options for decomposition there are

Decompose by business capability
Decompose by subdomain


Service-oriented architecture (SOA)

Also potentially interesting:

Domain-driven design (DDD)
SOA versus microservices: What's the difference?


I also read part of the book on Microservice Architecture Patterns, and I agree with what you said about according to business capabilities or according to subdomains, but are there any principles to help how to divide the microservices (subsystems) when practicing this is what I'm wondering about

@csucjh the "businesses capability" is quite straightforward, and for the domain one - see DDD

thanks for answer this question, I will deepen my understanding of DDD

There are many different architectural styles. But I would start by focusing not on specific styles, but on the characteristics you want to achieve. And these are essentially two characteristics:

Loose coupling
High cohesion


It's a bit abstract. Can you be more specific?

@csucjh hello. I know that a little bit “abstract”. May be it will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000762/what-does-low-in-coupling-and-high-in-cohesion-mean

thanks for you, I will take the time to read the link you posted
