# What is the relationship between code coupling, cohesion and fragility?

Tags: oop, refactoring, loose-coupling, coupling, cohesion

I am trying to understand code coupling, cohesion and fragility. I wanted to check my current understanding. Currently I have come up with following conclusions:

**low coupling = high cohesion = low fragility**

and vice-versa:

**high coupling = low cohesion = high fragility**

When I use **"="** I mean that achieving any of the three will achieving the other two. Is this true or not or are their any exceptions to this. Example with facts would be more useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cohesion & Coupling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085285/cohesion-coupling)