# UsersService or PostsService should create post for user?

Tags: design-patterns, service, repository-pattern, nest

I have PostsRepository where I handle the process of post creation for user.
But where "PostsRepository.create" method should be executed? In UsersService or PostsService?

Answer (score 0):

> But where "PostsRepository.create" method should be executed? In UsersService or PostsService?

`PostsRepository.create` should be executed in `PostsService` as `PostsService` should concern only about `Posts`. `UsersService` should have methods which have [high cohesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085285/difference-between-cohesion-and-coupling) with `UsersService`. I mean `UsersService` should only have methods which work only with `Users`.