# Cohesion principle in a class diagram (online shop)

Tags: oop, uml, software-design, class-diagram, cohesion

I would like to know which of the following 2 versions is the "more correct" according to the cohesion principle.

**Version #1:** my main thought was answering the question (what can/does a customer do?)

[image: (online-shop)class diagram, customer-order]

**Version #2:** here I was thinking that methods relating to orders such as(view order, cancel order...) should be defined in the class order too.

[image: (online-shop class diagram, customer-order)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Cohesion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) is about related responsibilities and clear purpose.  The more different, unrelated responsibilities, the less cohesive a class is (see also this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085285/3723423)). A pragmatic advice from OOP pioneer Rebecca Wirfs-Brock and Alan McKean is in their book [Object Design](https://wirfs-brock.com/DesignBooks.html) (which they now made available for free):

> A good test of whether an object is well formed is that its responsibilities form a cohesive unit. Does it stick to its purpose? Are its responsibilities clearly stated? Do they match its role?

**Option #1** is not cohesive.  The responsibilities of `Customer` is about profile management, authentication, and order management. One could claim that the two first are related, but the last one does clearly not belong there.  By the way, option #1 does not comply with the single responsibility principle, nor even with fundaments of encapsulation (`Customer` can access `Order`'s internals,  worse:  it has to). This last observation let us conclude that Order needs the Customer for managing it, and `Customer` could not work with a different `Order`, which shows a strong coupling in addition to low cohesion.

**Option #2** is cohesive.  `Customer` is only about managing the customer (including login and logout), and `Order` is only about managing the orders.

*As a side remark: your option #1 is not realistic from an UML point of view, since all the properties are private,  but no operation exist to access them ;-)*

Comment: the operations to access private properties were left out to make the diagram easier to read, but yeah, reading the explanation as to why the 2nd version is a better approach has put my mind at ease, thanks for the answer!