# Tight and loose coupling

Tags: spring, coupling

Can someone please explain why the first block of code is tightly coupled while the other one is loosely coupled?

```
// tightly coupled
class Employee {  
    Address address;  
    Employee(){  
        address=new Address();  
    }  
}

//loosely coupled
class Employee { 
    Address address;  
    Employee(Address address){  
       this.address=address;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coupling and cohesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946/coupling-and-cohesion)

Comment: thanks for your efforts andre , i already knew the definition , It would have been wonderful , if you had answered in terms of the above code which i have mentioned.

Comment: We would need to look for the exact case of use to determine if the case happens to be tightly coupled. In your case, with `Employee` and `Address` entities, it makes sense for the `Employee` class not to create the address itself, but to have it injected externally on the object creation or using a setter. This way we allow an external framework (like hibernate or spring) manage it and we can have many employees with the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Employee class needs an Address, so Address is a dependency of Employee.

```
// tightly coupled
class Employee {  
    Address address;  
    Employee(){  
        address=new Address();  
    }  
}
```

In first case, Employee is responsible for creating the instance of Address and hence Employee is tightly coupled to Address.

```
//loosely coupled
class Employee { 
    Address address;  
    Employee(Address address){  
       this.address=address;  
    }  
}
```

In second case Address will be given to Employee externally, so Employee is not tightly coupled to Address.

Let's take an example. Here we have two implementations of `Address` i.e. `HomeAddress` and `WorkAddress`. Since in first case `Employee` is responsible for instantiating  `Address`, it's tightly coupled to either home or work address. However, in second case `Employee` class can use any `Address` that has been given to it.